# Why `Error:(3, 1) TS1238:Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression` error

Tags: typescript

I have the following decorator:

```
export function MyClassDecorator(): PropertyDecorator {
    return function (target: Function) {
        Object.seal(target);
        Object.seal(target.prototype);
    }
}
```

And I use like that:

```
import {ClassDecorator} from "./class-decorator";

@MyClassDecorator()
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

However, `tsc` reports and error:

```
Error:(3, 1) TS1238:Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

The fix would be to change `PropertyDecorator` to `ClassDecorator`:

```
export function MyClassDecorator(): ClassDecorator {
```

However, the question is why the error with `PropertyDecorator`?

Here is how class and property decorators are declared in `lib.d.ts`:

```
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
declare type PropertyDecorator = (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void;
```

Answer (score 0):

Property decorators are used inside the class [definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), and not above the class. Your property decorator is where a class decorator should be placed.

The warning related to signatures could be appearing because the `target` parameter in ClassDecorator must actually be a constructor function, whereas in PropertyDecorator it is a more general object. Perhaps TS is able to pick up the difference based upon where you place the decorator.

For example, if you just remove the return type for MyClassDecorator then TS automatically picks up the type for this function and everything works:

```
function MyClassDecorator() {
    return function (target: Function) {
        Object.seal(target);
        Object.seal(target.prototype);
    };
}

@MyClassDecorator()
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```